# Angular ion-radio filter data from external db

Tags: angularjs, azure, ionic-framework

I have 2 tables in Azure db 1 called team and 1 called league, the id in league is also associated to a team e.g. team a belongs to leagueID 1.  I am trying to use ion-radio so users can choose their team but filter it by the league but cannot work out whether ng-if or filter is the best option. I have set up a service to call the data from azure: services.js

```
     .factory('League', function ($ionicPopup) {
     var url = 'http://';
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(url);
var LeagueTable = client.getTable('League');

function refreshDisplay() {
    return LeagueTable
        .read()
        .then(createList, handleError);
}

function createList(items) {
    return items;
}

function handleError(error) {
    var LeagueName = error + (error.request ? ' - ' + error.request.status :      '');
    console.error(LeagueName);
    console.log('error', error.request.status);
    if (error.request.status == '0' || error.request.status == '404') {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Connection Failure',
            template: 'Connection with backend can not be established.'
        });
    }
}
return {
    all: function () {
        return refreshDisplay();
    },
};
})






 .factory('Team', function ($ionicPopup) {
var url = 'http://';
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(url);
var TeamTable = client.getTable('Team');

function refreshDisplay() {
    return TeamTable
        .read()
        .then(createTeamList, handleError);
}

function createTeamList(items) {
    return items;
}

function handleError(error) {
    var text = error + (error.request ? ' - ' + error.request.status : '');
    console.error(text);
    console.log('error', error.request.status);
    if (error.request.status == '0' || error.request.status == '404') {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Connection Failure',
            template: 'Connection with backend can not be established.'
        });
    }
}
    return {
    all: function () {
        return refreshDisplay();
    },
}
  });
```

The controller at the moment just pulls back all the teams, controller.js:

```
   .controller('LeagueCtrl', function ($scope, $window, League) {

  $scope.doRefresh = function () {
    League.all().then(function (newList) {
        $scope.items = newList;
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        $scope.$apply();
    });

};

$scope.doRefresh();
console.log(League);
$scope.League;

     })




   .controller('TeamCtrl', function ($scope, $window, Team) {

   $scope.doRefresh = function () {
    Team.all().then(function (newList) {
        $scope.items = newList;

        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        $scope.$apply();
        return $scope.items
    });
};


$scope.doRefresh();
 });
```

And the HTML teams.html:

```
  <ion-view view-title="Choose your Team">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">

</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content>
    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
                   on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>

      <div ng-controller="SportCtrl">
        <h2> Choose sport</h2>
        <ion-radio  ng-model="item.complete" ng-repeat="item in items" >   {{item.text}}</ion-radio>
    </div>

        <div ng-controller="LeagueCtrl">
            <h2> Choose Conference</h2>
            <ion-radio ng-model="item.complete" ng-repeat="item in items">     {{item.LeagueName}}</ion-radio>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="TeamCtrl">
            <h2> Choose Team</h2>
            <ion-radio ng-model="item.complete" ng-repeat="item in items">    {{item.TeamName}}</ion-radio>
        </div>
    <div >
    <button class="button button-large-font-size button-block button-    assertive" ui-sref="app.home">Booyah</button>
        </div>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

As the scopes in different controller are separate, so there is a simple solution, you can put the `League` and `Team` in a same controller and in a same scope, then you can custom a filter function in your controller to achieve your requirements.

Generally:

```
<div ng-controller="LeagueTeamCtrl">
        <h2> Choose Conference</h2>
        <ion-radio ng-model="data.league_id" ng-repeat="item in league" ng-value="item.id">{{item.LeagueName}}</ion-radio>

        <h2> Choose Team</h2>
        <ion-radio ng-model="data.team_id" ng-repeat="item in team" ng-value="item.id">{{item.TeamName}}</ion-radio>
    </div>
```

And the custom filter function:

```
$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
   return item.leagueId === $scope.league_id ; 
};
```

And you can refer to the full example at http://codepen.io/liuguixiao/pen/ZpYLAB